# Solve for x- multiple x's exponents

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble with a question and any guidance would be appreciated.

[Here is a link to the equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbDlJ.png)

I'm thinking you'd have to switch the (1/9)^x and the 3^x+2. and then use exponent laws. However, after that, I'm not sure. Any tips, solutions would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{3^ \frac{x}{x+2}}{(\frac{1}{9})^x} = 3^{x+2}$

$\frac{3^ \frac{x}{x+2}}{3^{-2x}} = 3^{x+2}$

$3^ {\frac{x}{x+2}-(-2x)} = 3^{x+2}$

$ \frac{x}{x+2}+2x = x+2$

$x + 2x^2 + 4x=x^2 + 4x+4$

$x^2 + x -4=0$

Now it's just a quadratic equation

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in  \mathbb{R}$, $x \ne -2.$

take $\log_3$ of both sides:

$\frac{x}{x+2} \log_3(3)  + 2x\log_3(3) = (x+2)\log_3(3)$.

Note : $\log_3(3) =1.$

$x +2x(x+2) = (x+2)^2.$

Quadratic equation,  solve for $x.$

Used: $\dfrac{1}{(1/9)^x} = 3^{2x}.$